# Making a chrome extension that needs to save images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that will need to save images for its own use. I checked the chrome storage API but it doesn't look like it's able to store images or store very many. It cannot just save the URL to an image, it needs to be able to store the actual file. The only ways I can think of doing this is to either store the images on the user's computer (don't really want to do that) or setup a server where the images are uploaded (my only worry is cost because I don't see the chrome extension making money and if it does not that much).

Comment: You can use [HTML5 FileSystem](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: I took a look at that looks like it will work perfectly thanks.